# Getting the Id of a react-native element in event handler

Tags: react-native

How to get the Id of the element in onPress event handler.

I am adding elements dynamically and wants to know in the event handler of onPress of these elements to store in the state which elements are clicked.

Here is the code i have

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
         super(props);

         this.getElements= this.getElements.bind(this);
         this.selectElement = this.selectElement.bind(this);
       }

       componentWillMount(){
         this.state = {
           noOfElements :10
         }
       }

       selectElement(e,key){
          console.log('selectElement() : key=',key);
       }

       getElements(){
          let elements =[];
          for(let index=0;index<this.state.noOfElements;index++){
             elements.push(
                    <View key={'View_'+index} style={{flex:1}}>
                           <Button 
                              key={'View_'+index}
                              id={index}
                              onPress={(e,index) => {this.selectElement(e,index)}}    
                              title={'Button-'+index}
                           />
                    </View>
             );
          }
          return elements;
       }
       render(){
           let elements = this.getElements();
           return(
              <View style={styles.container}>
                 <Text>Test</Text>
                 {elements}
              </View>
           );
       }
    }
```

I tried just passing the key like

```
onPress={(index) => {this.selectElement(index)}}
```

with no success..

Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, i think index would come up undefined, just remove index as an argument in your onPress so it grabs index from the for loop. Also you can prob refactor it using map.

```
onPress={(e) => this.selectElement(e,index)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the event handler as below and it is working fine now.

```
onPress={this.selectElement.bind(this,index)}
```

and the function now just accepts the index

```
selectElement(key){
      console.log('selectElement() : Index=',key);
   }
```

Comment: Don't bind functions within JSX. Either use the constructor or a fat arrow.